# RespondCMS created site not working

Tags: heroku, respondcms

So I installed RespondCMS on Heroku and all the tests are succesful (/api/site/test.php and /test/index.php). I can create a site, pick a theme and everything works fine. Login works too, administration is also working perfectly. 
The created site itself however doesn't work at all. I get those errors in the console: [image: console errors]

 I read that heroku doesn't allow writable directories, so my first guess would be that the /sites directory isn't writable even though the test says the opposite...?

Comment: No, I had to give up on it. I think it really is due to the not allowed writable directories, which would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are the .htaccess files present? Also the sites folder needs to be writable so if that is not possible on heroku that will be an issue unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but double check the setup.php file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the site is not be written to the file system.  The login and administration piece is powered by the DB, so it could easily seem like the site has been created without it being in the file system.  Are you seeing your site in the sites directory?